# Colon ':' in column error - Not all named parameters have been set in Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent

I have a table with columns that have colons within. I am trying to figure out a way to ignore the colon as a parameter when trying to query the DB. I have tried to use SetParameter and String.Format but it does not work. I have also tried to escape the colon with a :: and \ but no luck. See a sample below

```
var result = session.CreateSQLQuery("Select id, [Results: A] as ResultsA, [Results: B] as ResultsB FROM Table").SetResultTransformer(Transformers.Alias.ToBean<TableObject>()).List<TableObject>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape `colons` and `\` too.

Try to replace `:` by `\\:`

Alternatively, [you can add `@`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) before your string to avoid `\\`

like this:

```
var result = session.CreateSQLQuery(@"Select id, [Results\: A] as ResultsA, [Results\: B] as ResultsB FROM Table").SetResultTransformer(Transformers.Alias.ToBean<TableObject>()).List<TableObject>();
```

Comment: No luck, when I use the @ or the \\: it makes the query Select id, [Results\\: A] as ResultsA, [Results\\: B] as ResultsB FROM Table, but it still sees the colon as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Check the exception details, and SQL that is actually send to DB.